# Find the avg of a set and the class using a text file in java

Tags: java, text-files, readfile

Marks for a class are stored in a text file called “marks3.txt”. The marks are saved in the following format: The first number represents the total number of (two-digit) marks stored sequentially in each line of text. Each line of text represents a set of marks.

For example (the txt file would contain the following numbers)
4567687509
569563

the marks are:

45%, 67%, 68%, 75%, 9%

56%, 95%, 63%

Write a method that will calculate the average of each set of marks as well as the overall average.

Below is the code I have created, I'm confused on how I would loop through the file until I have the two numbers that would make up the mark. Another thing I'm stuck on is how the method would be called.

```
import java.io.*;


public class ReadFile {


public static int calcAvg (String x) throws IOException {
    int avg = 0;
    int count = 0;
    
    
    FileReader fr = new FileReader ("/home/sharma6a/marks.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
    
    while ((x = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (count <= 2) {
            
        }
    }
    
    br.close();
    
    return avg;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `String x` parameter? Why is there a check for `count <= 2`? Where do you get the individual numbers from each line? Start doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

considering an input file like

```
45676875
09569563
```

first I will have a method to read the file and transform it into a better structure to use.

```
   public List<Integer> readFile() throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = "";
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/main/resources/numbers.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= line.length() - 2; i+=2) {
                char[] chars = line.toCharArray();
                int number = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(chars[i]) + String.valueOf(chars[i+1]));
                numbers.add(number);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

then I will have the method to calculate the AVG

```
public float calcAvg(List<Integer> numbers) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int number: numbers){
            sum+= number;

        }
        return sum/(numbers.size());
    }
```

of course, you need a start method to make things happen

something like

```
public void init() throws IOException {
    List<Integer> numbers = readFile();
    float result = calcAvg(numbers);
    System.out.println(result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as that. You practically want people to do stuff for you, but this is a question and answer site. Here you'll see some code for getting the individual percentages. You'll figure the rest out.

```
File f = new File(path);
try {

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; i+=2) {

    double percentage = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(i, i+2)) / 100.0;

  }

} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```